# 502 Bad Gateway Nginx and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I am using a ready made Droplet with Ubuntu and Rails.

I did a pull from git and hosted my code and modified the following file `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`

```
server {
        listen   80;
        root /home/noise_application/noise/public;
        server_name _;
        index index.htm index.html;

        location / {
                try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app;
        }

        location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|mp3|flv|mpeg|avi)$ {
                        try_files $uri @app;
                } 

         location @app {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }        

}
```

After that i tried to restarted Nginx i am getting the **502 Gateway error**

**LOGs**

```
2014/11/26 07:56:47 [error] 670#0: *11 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 122.167.75.29, server: _, request$
2014/11/26 09:42:16 [error] 671#0: *36 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 122.167.75.29, server: _, request$
2014/11/26 09:45:44 [error] 6572#0: *5 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 122.167.75.29, server: _, request$
2014/11/26 09:55:52 [error] 6572#0: *12 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 122.167.75.29, server: _, reques$
2014/11/26 09:56:58 [error] 6572#0: *12 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 122.167.75.29, server: _, reques$
2014/11/26 09:58:30 [error] 6572#0: *12 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 122.167.75.29, server: _, reques$
2014/11/26 10:02:48 [error] 18374#0: *7 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 122.167.75.29, server: _, reques$
2014/11/26 10:06:31 [error] 21484#0: *1 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 122.167.75.29, server: _, request$
2014/11/26 10:08:04 [error] 21484#0: *5 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 122.167.75.29, server: _, reques$
2014/11/26 10:10:47 [error] 21484#0: *8 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 122.167.75.29, server: _, reques$
2014/11/26 10:14:07 [error] 21484#0: *11 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 122.167.75.29, server: _, reque$
2014/11/26 10:17:42 [error] 21484#0: *14 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 122.167.75.29, server: _, reque$
2014/11/26 10:22:08 [error] 21484#0: *17 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 122.167.75.29, server: _, reque$
2014/11/26 10:29:14 [error] 21484#0: *23 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 122.166.182.253, server: _, req$
2014/11/26 10:30:34 [error] 4385#0: *1 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 122.166.182.253, server: _, reque$
2014/11/26 10:36:44 [error] 4385#0: *5 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 122.166.182.253, server: _, reque$
2014/11/26 10:39:10 [error] 4385#0: *9 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 122.166.182.253, server: _, reque$
2014/11/26 10:41:44 [error] 4385#0: *13 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 122.166.182.253, server: _, requ$
2014/11/26 10:43:17 [error] 4385#0: *17 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 122.166.182.253, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.$
2014/11/26 10:46:12 [notice] 12550#0: signal process started
2014/11/26 10:47:06 [error] 12553#0: *21 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 122.166.182.253, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1$
2014/11/26 10:47:37 [emerg] 12561#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2014/11/26 10:47:37 [emerg] 12561#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2014/11/26 10:47:37 [emerg] 12561#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2014/11/26 10:47:37 [emerg] 12561#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2014/11/26 10:47:37 [emerg] 12561#0: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2014/11/26 10:47:37 [emerg] 12561#0: still could not bind()
2014/11/26 10:47:54 [notice] 12562#0: signal process started
```

Comment: can you post `nginx` log with error?

Comment: @Зелёный added the logs

Comment: where is `upstream` directive for `unicorn`?

Comment: @Зелёный i havent used unicorn. the droplet came with it by default i guess. can you help me solve it or share a reference link i can read up and solve it.

Comment: Read [`Deploy Rails app to digitalocean with nginx, unicorn, capistrano & postgres`](https://gist.github.com/JamesDullaghan/5941259)

Comment: @Зелёный thank you i will go through it and get back to you.

Comment: so basically i need to tell NginX where Unicorn is and let it run the Rails app?

Comment: basically yes, nginx should listen `port` or `socket` what created by `unicorn` nginx it is just proxy server above your app server.

Answer (score 1):

Your server section looks OK, but you must set upstream (in you case app_server):

```
upstream app_server {
   server unix:/tmp/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
server {...}
```

/tmp/unicorn.sock is unicorn socket, which must be defined with unicorn config (may vary).

Comment: I created a empty file /tmp/unicorn.sock, and did what u suggested but still same error is occurring.!!!